# Adding an "Unclassifiable" label for categories whose classification confidence is low

Tags: classification

Let's say I have data labeled with n labels and a classifier that outputs both the predicted label and the confidence it has in the classification (the softmax value for this label). I want to add another label for all the inputs whose classification confidence is below some value, which will serve as an indication to inputs I prefer not show their classification, as they are probably wrong.
My questions are:

1. Is there a standard name for this setting?
2. What is the correct way to do that?
3. Should I chose an arbitrary threshold and raise/lower it until I'm satisfied?
4. Should there be separate thresholds for each label?
5. what should I do if there are indeed different threshold for each label, but x is classified as y with confidence a and z with confidence a - 0.1 but y's threshold is a + 0.1 and z's threshold is a - 0.15?